# Is it possible to make a FONT CHOOSER using HTML's CANVAS context(ctx) with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

This is the HTML side of things, this just a simple selector that let the users select a font and send a call to function.

```
<select id="selecFontFamily" name="selectFontFamily" onchange="updateInputFont();">
            <option> Serif </option>
            <option> Arial Black </option>
            <option> Sans-Serif </option>                                  
            <option> Tahoma </option>
            <option> Courier New </option>
            <option> Verdana </option>
            <option> Lucida Sans Unicode </option>                               
            </select>
```

This is the Javascript side of things. As you can see I created a second function that gets the font selected and change it to the ctx's font attribute but its not working.

```
var ctx
    function generatePreview(name, imgSelector="#certificate-thumb img", vPos=200, font='serif') {     
        let $card1 = $('.column .is-4 .card').eq(0);
        if ($card1.hasClass('border-is-dark')) {
            
            ctx = $('#certificate-preview')[0].getContext('2d');
            let template = new Image();
            template.src = $('#template-thumb img').attr('src');
    
            
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 480, 320);
            ctx.drawImage(template, 0, 0, 480, 320);
    
            ctx.font = 'bold 18px Courier New'; //DEFAULT
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.fillText(name, 240, vPos);
    
            $(imgSelector).attr('src', $('canvas')[0].toDataURL('image/png', 1)).show();
            $('#certificate-thumb .dropbox').hide();
        };
    };
    
    function updateInputFont() {
            let ctx = $('#certificate-preview')[0].getContext('2d');
            var selector = document.getElementById('selecFontFamily');
            var family = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
            window.font = family;
            //alert("THIS FUNCTION IS RUNNING");   
            ctx.font = 'bold 20px' + window.font; //THIS SUPPOSED TO CHANGE THE FONT BUT NOT WORKING :(
            generatePreview(name, font);   
    };
```

Comment: What's the point of doing this in a canvas instead of with a plain `<div>` or something?

Comment: As you can see, I am creating a Certificate Generator, certificate like a reward for attending seminar etc, which you can see in the first function it is creating an image and on top of that are text (a user input e.g. names) so its not a simple div, the text input must me going with that canvas

Comment: Just going on a whim here but does `ctx.font = '...'` work in the first function? If so, then maybe all you need is a space after `20px`? ... `'bold 20px ' + window.font;`

Comment: There's no guarantee that the `ctx`es in the two functions share their `font` (or other) settings. You might want to refactor things so you have one function that's responsible for drawing everything given some settings as arguments.

Comment: Why are you yelling so much? (All caps is considered yelling on much of the internet).

Comment: You are also not using the `font` parameter in `generatePreview`. The function signature is `name, imgSelector, vPos, font` but you are calling it with only `name, font`. Using `let ctx =` in the second function is creating a new variable that is not exposed to the other function, just as AKX stated, so setting `ctx.font` won't work anyway.